# StreamReader - Reading from lines

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code;

```
Public Sub writetofile()

  ' 1: Append playername
    Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("highscores.txt", True)
        writer.WriteLine(PlayerName)
    End Using

    ' 2: Append score
    Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("highscores.txt", True)
        writer.WriteLine(Score)
    End Using

End Sub
```

What I now want to do is read all the odd lines of the file (the player names) and the even lines into two separate list boxes, how would I go about that??

I need to modify;

```
Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("file.txt")
            ' Read one line from file
            line = reader.ReadLine
        End Using
```

I have used one of the following solutions but cannot get it working :(

```
Public Sub readfromfile()
    Using reader As New StreamReader("scores.txt", True)
        Dim line As Integer = 0
        While Not reader.EndOfStream
            If line Mod 2 = 0 Then
                frmHighScores.lstScore.Items.Add(line)
            Else
                frmHighScores.lstScore.Items.Add(line)
            End If
            line += 1
        End While
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`Mod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) operator for this:

```
Using reader As New StreamReader("highscores.txt", True)
    Dim line As Integer = 0
    Dim text As String
    Do
        text = reader.ReadLine()
        If text = Nothing Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        If line Mod 2 = 0 Then
            ''# even line
        Else
            ''# odd line                        
        End If
        line += 1
    Loop
End Using
```

This approach also works for cases when it's not an even/odd pattern, but another number of repetions. Say you have 3 lines for each player:

```
player name 1
score 1
avatar url 1
player name 2
score 2
avatar url 2
...
```

Then you can get this pattern by using `Mod` with 3

```
Dim subLine As Integer = line Mod 3
If  subLine = 0 Then
    ''# player name
ElseIf subLine = 1 Then
    ''# score                 
Else
    ''# avatar url
End If
line += 1
```

Comment: Actually, that will be an endless loop because your While loop has no statement that advances the stream pointer!  You need a ReadLine or something in there somewhere.

Comment: @Chris: you are absolutely correct, thanks for pointing it out. Updated answer to be more complete (that's what I get for not actually running the code).

Answer (score 3):

If you can reliably expect there to be an even number of lines in the file, then you can simplify this by reading two at a time.

```
Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("file.txt")
    While Not reader.EndOfStream
        Dim player as String = reader.ReadLine()
        Dim otherInfo as String = reader.ReadLine()

        'Do whatever you like with player and otherInfo
    End While
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know the syntax of VB but something like this:

```
dim odd as boolean = True
Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("file.txt")
            line = reader.ReadLine
            if odd then 
                ' add to list A
            else
                ' add to list B
            end
            odd = Not Odd
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to just read the whole file as a block into a single string and the SPLIT the string on vbcrlf

```
    Dim buf = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Filename)
    Dim Lines() = Split(Buf, vbcrlf)
```

Then, lines will contain all the lines from the file, indexed.

So you could step through them to get each player and his other info.

```
 For x = 0 to ubound(Lines)
       'do whatever with each line
 next
```

If the file was HUGE, you wouldn't necessarily want to do it this way, but for small files, it's a quick and easy way to handle it.